# Adding a new column to one dataframe using a column from a second consisting of vectors with strings in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to add a new column to a dataframe, the data will be filled from column A in second dataframe and depend on column B. The values in Column B are vectors. The length of vectors in my real data are far too long for an if_else statement, I'm looking for something more along the lines of stringer or grepl recognizing character strings but cycling through the rows of the dataframe like a for loop.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c('siteA', 'siteB', 'siteC', 'siteD'),
                  col2 = c('ecoA', 'ecoB', 'ecoC', 'ecoD'))

df2 <- data.frame(colA = c('type1', 'type2'),
                  colB = c("c('ecoA','ecoC')", "c('ecoB','ecoD')"))
```

I've tried merge, mutate with if statements, joins (dplyr), and case when, but again these either didn't fill all of the rows or they're far too long/complicated for the data set I have.

This is the end result I'm hoping for:

```
|col1 | col2 |colA |
|-----|------|-----|
|siteA| ecoA |type1|
|siteB| ecoB |type2|
|siteC| ecoC |type1|
|siteD| ecoD |type2|
```

Comment: When you put quotes around a vector definition like `"c('ecoA','ecoC')"`, it's not a vector anymore, it's just a string. You should use a `list` class column so that you can actually have vectors in there. The easiest place to fix that is when `colB` is created - if you have control over that.

Answer (score 2):

You could `parse` `colB` character string to transform it to a vector of character strings and `unnest` it:

```
df2$colB <- lapply(df2$colB,function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
df2 <- tidyr::unnest(df2,cols=colB)
dplyr::inner_join(df1,df2,by = c(col2="colB"))

   col1 col2  colA
1 siteA ecoA type1
2 siteB ecoB type2
3 siteC ecoC type1
4 siteD ecoD type2
```